# Why does my browser not open a websocket connection?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I am trying to create a websocket connection to a server. However, chrome tells me "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9898/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE" in the browser console when I open the html client.

Server:
´´´

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  socket.write('SERVER: Hello! This is server speaking.\n');
  socket.end('SERVER: Closing connection now.\n');
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

server.listen(9898, () => {
  console.log('opened server on', server.address().port);
});
```

´´´
Client:
´´´

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebSocket Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>

  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9898');

  ws.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log('An error occured: \n' + e);
  };

  ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    ws.send('Hi this is web client.');
  };

  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
  };
</script>
</html>
```

´´´
Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite embarrassing:  My understanding now is that net creates a TCP server. To create a websocket server, I now used the ws package.